# How to modify bar width in Chartjs 2 bar charts

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

Can someone told me how to modify bar width in Chartjs 2 bar charts. There is nothing about it in the documentation.

https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/tree/v2.0-dev/docsI don't know what to do.

Comment: [barStrokeWidth](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options) might be what you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Note that there seems to be some changes going on. The actual configuration would depend on which v2.0 you are using.*

**For Version 2.0.0-alpha**

Set `categorySpacing` for the xAxes. You can do this globally

```
Chart.defaults.bar.scales.xAxes[0].categorySpacing = 0
```

or you can do it by chart

```
...
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        categorySpacing: 0
    }],
...
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/beehe4eg/

---

**For Version 1.0.2**

Adjust the options `barValueSpacing` and `barDatasetSpacing` to make the bars closer. This will automatically increase their width.

Comment: It might have changed thence, the above answer was for 2.0.0-alpha.

Answer (score 40):

For version 2.4.0
barThickness - Manually set width of each bar in pixels. If not set, the bars are sized automatically.

```
options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barThickness : 73
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: barThickness is the *only* option I can get to work on a horizontalBar chart. I don't like having to set the value so specifically - wish I could get percentage working.

Comment: so still no way to set a max height for when there are only one or two values, then it can auto-calculate it otherwise?

Comment: This kind of worked for me. I'm not using a linear scale, so I went with `barPercentage`

Answer (score 17):

For me, trying 2.0 beta, what worked was to set the barPercentage on the xAxes scale option.

This is what I used:

```
var options = {
    data: chartData,
    type: "bar",
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{ barPercentage: 0.5 }]
        }
    }
};
var chart = new Chart(chartCtx, options);
```