# How to set bar width

Tags: chart.js

Please help out how to set bar width for dynamic values. I want fixed width for single value:

```js
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["January"],
    datasets: [{
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: "red",
      data: [65, 4, 30, 20, 70],
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      data: [-65]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:600px">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify bar width in Chartjs 2 bar charts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188888/how-to-modify-bar-width-in-chartjs-2-bar-charts)

Comment: No,waht i want is totally different from this solution